# Require property to all childen in json schema v4

Tags: json, jsonschema

Let say I have a schema like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 4,
      "maxLength": 50,
      "pattern": "[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\s]+"
    },
    "object": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "object"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Where 'object' can be an instance of any valid JSON object, 
but I want to enforce that every child object of the top-level object MUST have a property of 'sort_default' with values of enum ['ASC','DESC]

So a valid example instance might could be:

```
{
  "name": "Example Object",
  "object": {
    "prop1": {
      "value": 2547,
      "sort_default": "ASC"
    },
    "prop2": {
      "value": 3658,
      "sort_default": "DESC",
      "prop2.1": {
        "value": 147,
        "sort_default": "ASC"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but if an object node were missing the sort_default property, it would not validate.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a recursive definition of object schema, as [it is described here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/json-schema/z-MkAZ7Z47Y/p3OU10MGkB0J).